# Share a URL as post in Facebook App from React-Native App

Tags: react-native

I have a React-native app, from which I want share my website's URL in a Facebook post.
My current code is :

```
import Share from "react-native-share";

  const shareToFacebook = async () => {
    const shareOptions = {
      social: Share.Social.FACEBOOK,
      message: "Test message",
      url: "https://example.com/",
    };
    try {
      const ShareResponse = await Share.shareSingle(shareOptions);
      console.log(ShareResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error =>", error);
    }
  };
```

but this solution ,opens Facebook in the browser. Is there any way to open the actual Facebook app ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one with **react-native-share ^9.0.2**

```
Share.shareSingle({
        title: "TITLE",
        message: "MESSAGE",
        url: "URL",
        social: Share.Social.FACEBOOK,
        type: 'url',
      })
    .then((res) => { console.log(res) })
    .catch((err) => { err && console.log(err); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook offers an SDK for sharing posts, you can use that SDK with [react-native-fbsdk-next](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next) library. It shows an in-app modal. I think showing an in-app modal is better than the open the Facebook app or open a browser because some people do not have Facebook on their phones.

You can test the share function before installing the library, follow below steps:

```sh
# clone the react-native-fbsdk-next
git clone https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next.git

# go to the test project
cd RNFBSDKExample

# install dependencies
npm install

# run the project
npm run android
```

Example code (from README page):

```js
// ...

import { ShareDialog } from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';

// ...

// Build up a shareable link.
const shareLinkContent = {
  contentType: 'link',
  contentUrl: "https://facebook.com",
  contentDescription: 'Wow, check out this great site!',
};

// ...

// Share the link using the share dialog.
shareLinkWithShareDialog() {
  var tmp = this;
  ShareDialog.canShow(this.state.shareLinkContent).then(
    function(canShow) {
      if (canShow) {
        return ShareDialog.show(tmp.state.shareLinkContent);
      }
    }
  ).then(
    function(result) {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        console.log('Share cancelled');
      } else {
        console.log('Share success with postId: '
          + result.postId);
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log('Share fail with error: ' + error);
    }
  );
}
```

Read more about [Facebook Sharing Feature](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next#sharing).